# How to send scrapy command line argument to scrapyd-client

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd-deploy

I want to schedule a spider from scrapyd-client by giving the command line arguments as well.

e.g: scrapy crawl spider_name -a person="John" -a location="porto" -o local.csv

Above command works well when running spider directly from scrapy, but it does not work when running it from rest API using scrapyd-client.

Basically the question is how to send scrapy's command line arguments like (-a, -o) in scrapyd-client?

Answer (score 0):

Use the flag `-d` instead of the `-a` flag

Comment: Hi I tried using -d, but the results were same:  `code` **path_to_scrapyd-client schedule -p project_name spider_name -d person=John -d location=porto -o indeed_jobs_data.csv**

Comment: You should implement the csv saving logic in the spider using `FEEDS` setting in `custom_settings`. Then run command as below `path_to_scrapyd-client schedule -p project_name spider_name -d person=John -d location=porto`

Comment: This command is giving following error: **scrapyd-client: error: unrecognized arguments:  -d person=john -d location=porto**